# How to create knockout observable subscription that fires only once?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my model I have a property that is loaded asynchronously. I want it to generate another model property after it loads.

I was thinking about subscription that could fire after the 1st property changes, generates the 2nd property and then get disposed - I don't know how can I dispose subscription from inside itself.

Is there a way to fire one time event after observable property changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write an extender to suppress all but the first firing:

```
ko.extenders.fireOnce= function(target) {
    var fired=false;
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target();
            if (newValue!== current && !fired) {
                fired=true;
                target(newValue);
            }
        }
    });
    result(target());
    return result;
};
```

then use it as follows:

```
var myObservable = ko.Observable(blah).extend({fireOnce:null});
```

Comment: This extender should be named `changeOnce`, because all value changes except first will be ignored.

Comment: @blazkovicz ...and that's your basis for a downvote?

Comment: yes, because question was about subscription, thast fires once, and you suggested an observable that _changes once_. These are two hugely different things.

Answer (score 26):

To dispose subscription from inside itself just create reference to it:

```
var subscription = yourObservable.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    ...
    subsription.dispose();
});
```

If you don't want to write this code every time, you can extend observable with new method:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeOnce = function (handler, owner, eventName) {
    var subscription = this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        subscription.dispose();
        handler(newValue);
    }, owner, eventName);
    return subscription;
};

...

// usage
var subscription = yourObservable.subsribeOnce(yourHandler);
```

And dont' forget to dispose subscription on component disposal in case it was not fired.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up with a solution like this ...

```
const subscription = observable.subscribe(() => {
  subscription.dispose();
  doStuff(settings);
});
```

Hope somebody can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @blazkovicz answer, `subscribeOnce` could return a `Promise` eventually resolved with the new value. Open to suggestions on how to expose the `subscription` object ;-)

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeOnce = function (handler, owner, eventName) {
    var subscribable = this;
    var subscription;
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      subscription = subscribable.subscribe(resolve, owner, eventName);
    }).then(function(newValue) {
      subscription.dispose();
      handler && handler(newValue);
      return newValue;
    });
};

// usage
yourObservable.subscribeOnce().then(function(newValue) {
    ...
});
```